# How to find where a particular file is located using JAVA/KOTLIN code?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

My Windows app creates a "foo.txt" file. I ask my clients who are using this application to copy this file into their mobile devices in the DOWNLOAD folder so that my Android App can access and read this file for important data. But many of them put this in any of DOCUMENTS, PICTURES, MUSIC folders or into the REMOVABLE SD CARD. How to find where they have copied this file and its path using JAVA/KOTLIN code?

Comment: "I ask my clients who are using this application to copy this file into their mobile devices in the DOWNLOAD folder so that my Android App can access and read this file for important data" -- you will not have access to that file on Android 11+. "How to find where they have copied this file and its path using JAVA/KOTLIN code?" -- use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument` and let the user choose the file. Not only will you have access to it, but you do not need to guess at its location.

Comment: I would simply call that a bad app design. If the file is not too large I would consider your Windows app to display a QR code with a special scheme that is registered by your app like `myapp://host/data123`. Then scanning the QR code and executing the link will open your app and you can process the URL and extract the data.

Answer (score 0):

UDATE: on Android getting the application directory can be achieved as follows:

```
Context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir
```

**Leaving the Windows OS part below for the sake of comment history tracking.**

The files your app writes need to have predefined location on every OS your java app works. There are System properties in java you can use to refer to OS specific location. For example to get the current working directory your application is running in:

```
public class JavaApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
  }
}
```

For getting the location where applications are meant to store their data on Windows you can use one of the following environment variables:

1. `%PROGRAMDATA%`
2. `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%`

Personally, I think that %PROGRAMDATA% is a better fit.

You can get the value of the environment variable like this:

```
String programDataDir = System.getenv("PROGRAMDATA");
```

Comment: None of this is relevant for Android. For example, Android programs do not implement a `main()` method.

Comment: @CommonsWare, you are right. I got confused by the way the question begins “My Windows app…”. However, the principle is pretty much the same to all platforms I believe. Main - is just a code snippet, could be dropped and only the line for actual  read of env variable  is relevant

Comment: "the principle is pretty much the same to all platforms I believe" -- not for Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare updated the answer. The principle is very much the same

Comment: Please ignore the Windows App portion of my question. My specific requirement is a piece of code written in JAVA/KOTLIN in Android studio to search everywhere in the mobile and find a specific file “foo.txt” in the external storage. 
My code in Kotlin works if the file is present in known folders. What if I want to look into subfolders ? And how to read into a removable SD card ?
Is it possible to run through the entire Directory Tree in search of a file ?
In Kotlin there is a function FILES.WALK but I do not know what id does and how to use it.

Comment: @aviad Please ignore the Windows App portion of my question. My specific requirement is a piece of code written in JAVA/KOTLIN in Android studio to search everywhere in the mobile and find a specific file “foo.txt” in the external storage. My code in Kotlin works if the file is present in known folders. What if I want to look into subfolders ? And how to read into a removable SD card ? Is it possible to run through the entire Directory Tree in search of a file ? In Kotlin there is a function FILES.WALK but I do not know what id does and how to use it

Comment: My recommendation (and the best practice) is to use a predefined location in file system for writing and reading files by your application. If you give users a flexibility to save files where they want and then will try to figure out later where the file you gave them was stored it will soon and surely turn into a mess. In your case, I would use /data/data/<package_name> (and corresponding SD-part):

databases/: here go the app's databases
lib/: libraries and helpers for the app
files/: other related files
shared_prefs/: preferences and settings
cache/: - caches